# Query entries between two values

Tags: entries, datetime, query

I am trying to query entries (scripts) when a custom expiration date field is within a certain range.

These questions/answers helped me get as far as I am, but I'm still stuck: [Advanced query/filter based on date and values](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11014/advanced-query-filter-based-on-date-and-values) and [How can you return elements between two values?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/how-can-you-return-elements-between-two-values)

Here's the full scenario. On this app's homepage, it lists a handful of recent scripts (prescriptions). It also has sections where it displays scripts that are expired and scripts that are about to expire (within two weeks of the current date).

I did some testing and found that the following conditionals filter the scripts just how I want:

```
{# When expiration date is between now and 2 weeks #}
{% if expirationDate >= now and expDate <= now|date_modify('+2 weeks') %}

{# When expiration date is anytime before now #}
{% if expirationDate < now %}
```

Those work great. **How can I move this filter into the query itself?**

I was thinking something like the following, but it obviously doesn't work because of all the commas. But this is what I'm trying to do. **How do I use this correctly in a hash?**

```
{% set scriptsAboutToExpire = {
    section: 'scripts',
    order: 'expirationDate asc',
    expirationDate: 'and', '>=' ~ now, '<=' ~ now|date_modify('+2 weeks')
} %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the answer to this thanks to @BrandonKelly from a comment in this question: [How can you return elements between two values?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/how-can-you-return-elements-between-two-values/1683?noredirect=1#comment30865_1683)

Turning it into a subarray does the trick: `expirationDate: [ 'and', '>=' ~ now, '<=' ~ now|date_modify('+2 weeks') ]`

Thanks, @BrandonKelly!

Comment: This is no longer accurate in Craft v3. The dates in the query need to be explicitly formatted as strings. For example `expirationDate: [ 'and', '>=' ~ now|date('U'), '<=' ~ now|date_modify('+2 weeks')|date('U') ]` See https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/25826